# Generate all spanning trees of the complete graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

How can you use Mathematica to generate all the spanning trees of the complete graph?

One can count the spanning trees of a connected graph ${G}$ using e.g. the Tutte polynomial $T_{G}(1,1)$.
For the complete graph $K_{n}$, the count is $T_{K_{n}}=n^{n-2}$. But this does not generate them.

One way is to use e.g. [Wilson's algorithm](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/11357811), and reject new picks if the new pick is identical to a previous pick, until you have $n^{n-2}$ different spanning trees.
But this requires randomly picking trees. Is there a better way?

Comment: BTW the random sampling technique you mentioned is implemented in `IGRandomSpanningTree`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean, generate all labelled trees on $n$ vertices.

Generate all Prüfer sequences and [convert them to trees with IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igfromprufer).

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

n = 4;
IGFromPrufer[#, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], n - 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know about these Prüfer sequences. I had thought IGraph would be good here.